# Problem generating 500 receipts HTML from a xsl generator

Tags: html, xslt

**I am generating a HTML about a 500 receipts from a xsl file but in the last two bills from the 500 they are not generated the way i want.**

**I get this error: Type error at char 26 in expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 17 column 174 of llista_factures.xsl:**
**XPTY0004  A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first operand of '*'****
**(<unitats>, <unitats>, <unitats>, ...)**
**In template rule with match="celler" on line 5 of llista_factures.xsl**
**invoked by built-in template rule (text-only)**
**[ERROR]: file:/C:/FP/Llenguatge%20de%20marques/TercerTrimestre/XML/AgendaXML/AgendaXML/ImportantEntrega/llista_factures.xsl: line 17: column 26: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first operand of '*****' (<unitats>, <unitats>, <unitats>, ...) I tried fixing the problem but it didnt worked. I also tried increasing the memory heap but i didn't change anything. If someone knows how i can fix it... ****

**The structure from the  1 bill should look like this, I am putting only 1 because the file extends up 52981 lines of coding:**

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Celler</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="estil_factures.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <h1>Distribucions Tunel</h1>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr colspan="3">
            <td>Factura: F000001</td>
            <td>Codi:C00071</td>
            <td class="columna_client">Client: Tomas Muñoz, Diana Iris</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Codi</td>
            <td>Producte</td>
            <td class="quantitat_columna">Quantitat</td>
            <td>Preu per unitat</td>
            <td>Preu Total</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>B5</td>
            <td>Vi blanc garrafa de 5 litres</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">5</td>
            <td>8.85€</td>
            <td>44.25€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>N1</td>
            <td>Vi negre botella d'1 litre</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">1</td>
            <td>2.00€</td>
            <td>2.00€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>N2</td>
            <td>Vi negre botella de 2 litres</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">2</td>
            <td>3.95€</td>
            <td>7.90€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>N3</td>
            <td>Vi negre garrafa de 3 litres</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">2</td>
            <td>5.45€</td>
            <td>10.90€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>N5</td>
            <td>Vi negre garrafa de 5 litres</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">1</td>
            <td>8.85€</td>
            <td>8.85€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>R1</td>
            <td>Vi rosat botella d'1 litre</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">1</td>
            <td>2.00€</td>
            <td>2.00€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>R5</td>
            <td>Vi rosat garrafa de 5 litres</td>
            <td class="columna_quantitat">5</td>
            <td>8.85€</td>
            <td>44.25€</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td align="right">total</td>
            <td align="right">120.15€</td>
         </tr>
```

**This is the XSL that generates the HTML:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="celler">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Celler</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="estil_factures.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="factures/factura"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="right">
                            <xsl:text>Total: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(factures/factura/unitats * //producte[@codi=current()/factures/factura/unitats/@codi]/@preu), '#.00€')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="factura">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <h1>Distribucions Tunel</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="3">

            <xsl:variable name="codi_client" select="comprador/@codi"/>
            <xsl:variable name="client" select="//client[@codi=$codi_client]"/>
            <td>Factura: <xsl:value-of select="@numero"/></td>
            <td>Codi:<xsl:value-of select="$client/@codi"/></td>
            <td class="columna_client">Client: <xsl:value-of select="$client/nom"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Codi</td>
            <td>Producte</td>
            <td class="quantitat_columna">Quantitat</td>
            <td>Preu per unitat</td>
            <td>Preu Total</td>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="unitats"/>

        <!-- Filas vacías -->
        <xsl:variable name="emptyRowCount" select="12 - count(unitats)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$emptyRowCount > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="emptyRow">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$emptyRowCount"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:variable name="total">
            <xsl:for-each select="unitats">
                <td>Codi</td>
                <xsl:variable name="codi_producte" select="@codi"/>
                <xsl:variable name="producte" select="//producte[@codi=$codi_producte]"/>
                <xsl:element name="parcial">
                    <xsl:for-each select=".">
                        <xsl:variable name="currentUnitat" select="."/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$producte/@preu">
                            <xsl:variable name="currentPreu" select="."/>
                            <parcial>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$currentUnitat * $currentPreu"/>
                            </parcial>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="white"></td>
        <td align="right">total</td>
        <td align="right"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($total/parcial),'#.00€')"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="emptyRow">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>
    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
        <tr class="empty-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="emptyRow">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="unitats">
    <xsl:variable name="codi_producte" select="@codi"/>
    <xsl:variable name="producte" select="//producte[@codi=$codi_producte]"/>
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$producte/@codi"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$producte"/></td>
        <td class="columna_quantitat"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number($producte/@preu, '#.00€')"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(. * $producte/@preu, '#.00€')"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the line 17 is e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(factures/factura/unitats * //producte[@codi=current()/factures/factura/unitats/@codi]/@preu), '#.00€')"/>` then the error tells you that `factures/factura/unitats` selects more than one `unitats` element. And the `*` operator needs to have a single item on the left or right.

Comment: Ohh it worked, I am grateful for this response from you. It has solved a major headache for me. You are a lifesaver